# docker mesosphere marathon - unable to see running process inside a docker container

Tags: tomcat, docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I am a newbie in mesos and marathon space. I have mesos slaves running my docker containers. I am using marathon to instantiate a mesos task. Here is my simple json file:

```
{
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "tomcat:8.0"
    }
  },
  "id": "tomcat",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.5,
  "mem": 512,
  "uris": [],
  "cmd": "while sleep 10; do date -u +%T; done"
}
```

I use curl and raise a post request using marathon. My docker container is deployed successfully as per marathon. Till here everything is fine. Now I ssh into my docker container using the command

sudo docker exec -i -t  /bin/bash

I do not see any log generated for tomcat. I feel my tomcat has not started. Running telnet 8080 fails as telnet is not available on the container. when I run ps -aef I see th following is available "/bin/sh -c while sleep 10; do date -u +%T; done". However I cannot still say whether tomcat is running. Has anyone faced such issue...any pointers to debug it.

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: I believe you have to use port mapping on your JSON file so that you can run the Tomcat server? You can also try netstat -an | grep 8080.

Comment: docker exec does not use SSH to enter a container. It uses kernel namespaces to start a new process inside a container, in this case a new shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSON file you should have `"cmd": ""` (last line) otherwise the docker container command is overridden.

Comment: You are an angel. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1507003 You're welcome. btw, it seems `cmd` is optional so you could completely remove the line. See: http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing this out. BTW is there some document which describes each of these tags and there usage?

Comment: @user1507003 I think this document is pretty detailed: http://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html